# Ease out animation for SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm moving a sprite by using the touchesMoved method. So far this is working fine, but the result looks a little bit unnatural. The sprite stops immediately, once the movement of my finger stops. A more natural impression would be, if the sprite continuous the movement a little time with an ease out function. Any idea how to implement this?

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var sprite: SKSpriteNode?
    var xOrgPosition: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        sprite!.xScale = 0.1
        sprite!.yScale = 0.1
        sprite!.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        self.addChild(sprite!)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let xTouchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self).x
            if xOrgPosition != 0.0 {

                // calculate the new position
                sprite!.position = CGPoint(x: sprite!.position.x - (xOrgPosition - xTouchPosition), y: sprite!.position.y)
            }

            // Store the current touch position to calculate the delta in the next iteration
            xOrgPosition = xTouchPosition
        }
    }



   override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        // Reset value for the next swipe gesture
        xOrgPosition = 0
   }
}
```

Update:
I've made a short sample project, based on the answers from hamobi

[Tutorial](http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2015/11/quick-tip-endless-scrolling-with-easing.html)
[Git repository](https://github.com/stfnjstn/EndlessScrollingDemo)

Comment: Try rather than just setting the position, give the node a physics body with velocity. Then have it slow down quickly rather than just stopping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this might be what youre going for.  let me know if you have any questions :)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var sprite: SKSpriteNode?
    var xOrgPosition: CGFloat?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        sprite!.xScale = 0.1
        sprite!.yScale = 0.1
        sprite!.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        self.addChild(sprite!)
    }


    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            xOrgPosition = touch.locationInNode(self).x
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        xOrgPosition = nil
    }


    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        if let xPos = xOrgPosition {
            sprite!.position.x += (xPos - sprite!.position.x) * 0.1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks a lot